# Как получить полный список организаций по адресу через Yandex API?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api, yandex-places-api

Пытаюсь получить список организаций по адресу с помощью [Поиска по организациям Yandex API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/). К сожалению, вывод на Yandex Картах и через API разительно отличается.

Несколько примеров:

1.
Адрес: Свердловская обл., Лесной, ул. Победы, 3
Ссылка на выдачу Yandex.Карт:

`https://yandex.ru/maps/11167/lesnoy/?ll=59.796869%2C58.626624&z=17&mode=search&text=%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%94%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF%2C%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%99%2C%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%95%D0%94%D0%AB%2C3&sll=59.796869%2C58.626523&sspn=0.015771%2C0.004790`

Блок "В этом доме" показывает две организации:

- Городская больница
- Медсанчасть №91

Запрос через Yandex.API:

`https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text= СВЕРДЛОВСКАЯ,ЛЕСНОЙ,ПОБЕДЫ,3&lang=ru_RU&type=biz&results=10&apikey=<API_KEY>`

выдаёт JSON с единственной организацией: Городская больница

2. Другой пример
   Адрес: СВЕРДЛОВСКАЯ,ЕКАТЕРИНБУРГ,МЕЛЬКОВСКАЯ,2Б

Yandex.Карты:

`https://yandex.ru/maps/54/yekaterinburg/?ll=60.602370%2C56.850417&z=17&mode=search&text=%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%94%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF%2C%20%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%91%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%93%2C%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF%2C2%D0%91&sll=59.796869%2C58.626624&sspn=0.015771%2C0.004991`

Показывает пару десятков огранизаций в доме.

Запрос через Yandex API:

`https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%94%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF,%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%91%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%93,%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF,2%D0%91&lang=ru_RU&type=biz&results=100&apikey=<API_KEY>`

JSON с ответом содержит 1 (одну) организацию: ТСЖ Мельковская 2 литер Б

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как получить полный список организаций по адресу?

Comment: В API нет возможности получить все  организации по адресу.

Comment: @Reni спасибо за комментарий! 

В описании сказано, что: "API Поиска по организациям позволяет находить организации по названию, **адресу**, номеру телефона, виду услуг." Из этого я сделал вывод, что могу найти организацию по адресу, но, получается, описание некорректное.

Я пытался по адресу получить координаты, а уже по координатам - все организации. Однако и тут список неполно-избыточен, т.е. в нём присутствуют не все организации по адресу, зато много лишних. Пробовал играть с spn и bbox, но универсального алгоритма не могу придумать. Не подскажете, куда можно попробовать копнуть?

Comment: Через API Яндекс.Карт _нельзя_ выгрузить все организации в доме. Это сделано специально, потому что API предполагает использование в поисковом сценарии, а не выгрузку каталога данных Яндекса. 
Адрес в поисковом запросе используется, например, чтобы выбрать не все аптеки в Москве, а аптеки на Садовом.

Comment: @Reni У меня задача не выгрузить всё из каталога, а дать пользователю возможность проверить наличие конкретной интересующей пользователя организации по заданному пользователем конкретному адресу. Пока я предполагаю, что более-менее точно я могу это сделать только получив список организаций по адресу и попытавшись провести нечёткий поиск, сравнивая список с полученным названием. Теоретически я могу задать И название организации, И адрес, но в этом случае очень часто выдаются организации с похожим названием по другому адресу, а вот адреса нормализовать и сравнивать уже гораздо сложнее.

Comment: @Reni в любом случае спасибо за ответы, я сделал вывод, что реализовать требуемое инструментами Yandex нельзя, придётся искать другие варианты.

Comment: в таком случае логичнее по адресу жестко ограничивать bounding box поискового запроса (у API есть такие параметры), а внутри этой области уже искать по тому названию, которое ввел пользователь, стандартными средствами API.